# How I can count char in a string and validate using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate a string in such a way that in must have 2 hypens(-)

**Strings input** : (for eg)

```
B405Q-0123-0600

B405Q-0123-0612

R450Y-6693-11H0

R450Y-6693-11H1
```

Comment: What are your other validation requirements?

Comment: just need to check if the string is having two hypens then it is valid in php

Comment: i just tried with the length only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) function like this

```
<?php
 echo substr_count( "B405Q-0123-0600", "-" )."\n";
 echo substr_count( "B405Q01230600", "-" )."\n";
?>
```

**Will Result**

```
2
0
```

Validate like this

```
if(substr_count( $some_string, "-" ) == 2)
{
       echo 'true';
       // do something here
}else
{
       echo 'false validation failed';
       // some error handling
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are like shown, then you can do

```
$re = "/(\\w{5}-\\w{4}-\\w{4})/"; 
$str = "B405Q-0123-0600"; // Your strings
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
   // valid
} else {
   // invalid
}
```

---

> I just need to check if the string is having two hyphens

If you only want to check if there are two hyphens *anywhere*, then you can split your strings on hyphens. If there are two and only two hyphens, then there will be 3 split parts.

```
$str = "B405Q-0123-0600"; // your strings
if (count(split("-", $str)) === 3) {
   // two hyphens present
} else {
   // not enough hyphens
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "B405Q-0123-0612";
var arr = str.split("-");

if(arr.length=3){
    alert("Your string contain 2 hyphens");
}
```

Comment: Wrong programming language

Answer (score 0):

For checking this type of validation you are required to use the Regex of javascript. Use below given regular expression.

```
var check="^\w+([\s\-]\w+){0,2}$";
```

Now all need is to check this with creating the javascript function and you are half the way there.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
  $string = "B405Q-0123-0612";

    $arr = explode("-",$string)

    if (count($arr) == 2)
    {
        //yes you have 2 hyphens
    }
```

The above procedure is the simplest way to do

Comment: I think you mean `$string = "B405Q-0123-0612";`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\-/",'B405Q-0123-0600',$match);
if(count($match[0]) == 2){
  // valid
}else{
  // invalid
}
```